# cocos2d-x pugi xml french words

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, pugixml

I had some problem with parsing xml document with french words. 
For example pêche
After parsing i have this: "p\xc3\xaache" instead of "pêche"

Here is my code:

```
    for(pugi::xml_node child = parent.first_child(); child; child = child.next_sibling()){
                    std::string desc = child.child_value("word");
}
```

Any suggestions?
Tnx.

Comment: It's escaped code of `pêche`, what's your problem?

Comment: how to convert it to normal characters?